# Call a method running on another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

I am creating multiple different threads from a single manager class. I now need to update each thread when a variable in the parent application changes.

So I would like to be able to call a function within the thread. What is the best approach? The thread has a reference to the manager class so I was thinking to poll a function in the manager from within the thread to check for changes to the variable, but that doesn't seem right, surely there is a better way. I looked at Dispatcher class but this didn't seem right either. Can anyone recommend the best approach to this?

```
    account1 = new Account(this);
    account2 = new Account(this);
    Thread accountThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(account1.Run));
    Thread accountThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(account2.Run));

    accountThread1.Start();
    accountThread2.Start();

    // How do I call method on accountThread1 or 2?
```

Comment: use a producer-consumer queue pattern. there is no calling into a thread - the thread is running your code.

Comment: Using Threads is discouraged, specially since you have the entire TPL that you can use. Follow @DanielA.White's advice and get familiar with `async`, `await` and `Task`s

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto everything has its place.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if something is cpu bound thats better for threads/workers, not async code.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but not enough information has been given to think that Tasks aren't better suited here. Well, there isn't enough information to even answer

Comment: "I need to periodically update each thread" I don't know what this means. A program doesn't update threads; it updates variables. So set up a variable somewhere where the threads can read it (e.g. a static global variable for example) and just update that. Bear in mind you may have to set up some sort of concurrency protection for that variable, e.g. using `lock`.

Comment: I have edited the question to give a more detailed description of what I am trying to achieve. Apologies if the original question was too vague.

Comment: @JohnWu -that sounds workable, I was just wondering if there is a way to call directly into the class running on each thread, rather than having a looper in each class /thread calling the parent to get updates.. I've updated my question to hopefully be clearer about what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: OP you are either confused or using terminology very strangely. You can't call into threads and classes (I think you mean objects) are not bound to threads (unless we are talking about STA controls which I doubt). Until you overcome this conceptual problem your question probably won't make any sense.

Comment: OK, thanks I'll talk to Senior Developers in my team to try and get a better understanding of threading concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this is to use an [Observer Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern) to effectively push variable changes into the threads achieving the required results.

Using an Observer Pattern all the running threads can watch a variable in parent application for changes. This way the threads do not poll the parent, but the threads can respond to changes in a variable in the main application, effectively allowing push of changed variables into all of the threads.

The MS Docs link is a bit complex. I found this was quite a nice easy to follow tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grHxRCtETP8

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it right, you want a proper way to handle the threads.
I couldnt give to you the proper way, but this is the way im handling my threads to get data from PLC 24/7 without crash.

Sample as below:

```
//Create list of thread
    private List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

    private void RunThread(YourClass yourclass)
    {
        switch (yourclass.ConnStat)
        {
            case ConnStatus.DISCONNECTED:
                {
                    Thread oldthread = threads.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == yourclass.ID.ToString());
                    if (oldthread != null)
                    {
                        //Clean old thread
                        threads.Remove(oldthread);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Add event here
                        yourclass.OnResponseEvent += new EventHandler<YourClass.ResponseEventArgs>(work_OnResponseEvent);
                        yourclass.OnNotificationEvent += new EventHandler<YourClass.NotificationEventArgs>(work_OnInfoEvent);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        //Add thread to list
                        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => yourclass.Initialize())) { Name = yourclass.ID.ToString(), IsBackground = true };
                        thread.Start();
                        threads.Add(thread);
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch (ThreadStateException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case ConnStatus.CONNECTED:
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ID:{0}, is currently running!", yourclass.ID));
                    break;
                }
            case ConnStatus.AWAITING:
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ID:{0}, is currently awaiting for connection!", yourclass.ID));
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    //To control your class within thread
    private void StopThread(YourClass yourclass)
    {
        if (yourclass.ConnStat == ConnStatus.CONNECTED || yourclass.ConnStat == ConnStatus.AWAITING)
        {
            //Call your method
            yourclass.Disconnect();

            yourclass.OnResponseEvent -= work_OnResponseEvent;
            yourclass.OnDBResponseEvent -= work_OnDBResponseEvent;
            yourclass.OnNotificationEvent -= work_OnInfoEvent;

            Thread oldthread = threads.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == yourclass.ID.ToString());
            if (oldthread != null) threads.Remove(oldthread);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps